# In Hive looking to select rows that have a special character in a column

Tags: sql, regex, hive, extract

I'm looking to SELECT rows in Hive that have a special character [a-zA-Z0-9] in a column.

I'm not quite sure how to construct the WHERE clause but based upon other threads I think it should look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_name
FROM user_info
WHERE user_name like regexp_extract('%[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]%')
```

but Hive provided this error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10014]: Line 3:21 Wrong arguments ''%[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]%'': No matching
>   method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with
>   (string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(string, string) *FUNC*(string,
>   string, int)

How should I set up the regexp_extract clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_name
FROM user_info
WHERE user_name rlike '[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:]'
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringOperators

```
hive> select 'Dudu Markovitz: 123' rlike '[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:]';
OK
false
hive> select 'Dudu Markovitz: @123' rlike '[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:]';
OK
true
```

Comment: This didn't produce an error but didn't produce the results I was expecting. Still testing. Thank you as I wasn't aware of the rlike feature.

Comment: Works great - definitely a solution for the question. Thanks